# Passing objects to a knockout view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can I perform a binding like this with knockout

```
<div data-bind="attr:{id: id,'data-plugin-options': options}">
```

My model looks something like

```
var model = {
    id: id,
    options: {
         headerText: 'Group',
         headerStyle: 'groupWithBorders'   
     }
};

ko.applybindings(model);
```

At the moment I get [object object] on data-plugin-options after the binding happens.

Comment: Don't forget to bind your model ko.applybindings(model);

Comment: Hmm I will edit the code sample to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout converts objects in the attr binding to strings using toString(). You could overload that function to output the results you want:

```
var model = {
    id: id,
    options: {
        headerText: 'Group',
        headerStyle: 'groupWithBorders',
        toString: function() {
            return JSON.stringify(this);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Was just about to answer the same. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UCQxL/2/

Comment: I am still getting [object object] on data-plugin-options. Might be worth going down jQuery way for this one. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: My bad did it at the wrong level. The solution actually works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
<div data-bind="attr:{id: id,'data-plugin-options': options.headerText}">


var model = {
    id: 'id',
    options: {
         headerText: 'Group',
         headerStyle: 'groupWithBorders'   
     }
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

And you will see this result :

```
<div data-bind="attr:{id: id,'data-plugin-options': options.headerText}" id="id" data-plugin-options="Group">
</div>
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9UWj/)**

I hope it helps.

Comment: I guess he want both the items.